# What constraints should i use?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

i have a TableViewCell and i want it to contain 2 labels both centered vertically in the cell, one at the left border and one at the right border(with respective text alignment). Now the right one should remain 1 line(its only a number with max 6 digits), but if the left one gets too big and would overlap the right one, i want it to make line breaks.

Now i've tried different approaches, for example i first added the right one and gave it the constraint "trailing space to superview = 0" and "center vertically in container".
Then i added the other one, gave it the constraints "leading space to superview = 0", "trailing space to rightLabel = 0" and "center vertically in container" and set lines to 0.

But that didn't work, it didnt make line breaks and overlapped the right label.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: You can use the same solution with hugging priority [solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39591074/5397625)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct content-hugging and compression-resistance priorities (by default they have the same value), that's why the system doesn't know which constraint to break.

Try changing the content-hugging and compression-resistance priorities so that they are no longer equal. The system breaks the constraint having the lowest priority first.

[image: content-hugging and compression-resistance]

Select the label. Open the Size inspector, find the Content Hugging Priority and Compression Resistance Priority settings. Change priorities.